# Revisions page says that questions [on hold] were 'closed as ""'

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, revisions-list

The close reason is missing for close events on the `posts/N/revisions` page for questions that are that are "on hold".

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This does not persist after the question has moved out of the "on hold" period.

[image]

It's arguable whether the "close" event should say "on hold" or "closed" for such questions, but presumably the close reason would be included in either case.

Comment: Hmm, I may be wrong about which questions are not affected by this. The close vote changes were rolled out about five days ago, so it's unclear whether the close reason is displayed correctly for questions that are no longer "on hold", or simply for questions that were closed before the changes were applied.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this but have not been able. Guess we will have to wait for the next "on hold" to see if this is still happening.

Comment: @Oded [freshly closed question revision list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/185173/revisions) - does it help?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yep. Helped point me in the right direction. To be continued...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while to track down.

Close reasons now show the "as" what.

Comment: But it is not fixed in the API on [`/posts/{ids}/revisions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids). The revision comment still says `&lt;b&gt;Post Closed&lt;/b&gt; as &quot;&quot;`.

Comment: @Antony - Yes, I had not fixed that specific code path for various reasons.